# How to pass username and password via REST call securely?

Tags: wcf, rest

I need to secure my REST call for accessing a service. My scenario was
i) Provide Username and Password from the rest call to access service
ii)At the backend, extract the U/P and from that need to access another service which will follow username authentication.

I have go through so many blogs that revealing to use "HTTPS" and some other said to use Basic and Digest authentication mechanism. I am new to this area and can anybody figured out me how to pass this scenario.

Comment: Please see the links which might be helpful.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/c399b15b-479c-4eb0-ac15-b3824a5e7617 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018416/restful-user-authentication-service

Answer (score 4):

Using HTTPS, all traffic will be encrypted securely, including the username and password.

This will however, encrypt the entire data stream.

This is what I would recommend if you are transporting information which is meant to be secure.

Comment: hi, https will avoid only man-in-middle attacks and it is a point-to-point method over wire. But i need to send U/P not as a plain text.

Comment: What type of security are you looking for then?

Comment: If HTTPS is a problem then you would need to encrypt the credentials and put them in the request Uri or body. However, this means you have to find a way of distributing the public key to clients for encryption and the client will have to have the capability to do encryption. This rules our browser clients for example. I agree with @adam king that HTTPS is the right way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPS is indeed point to point security mechanism.
But surely can't pass your username/password in REST url for authorization.

You can go with using dedicated API keys in service URLs. eg. maps.google,twitter.